# System.ArgumentException: No mapping exists from object type Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue to a known managed provider native type

Tags: c#, sql-server, api

I'm trying to execute a stored procedure from sql server, from my C# API, and it shows  System.ArgumentException: No mapping exists from object type Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue to a known managed provider native type. Error can anyone help with that please. the parameters are dynamic type.

```
                    dynamic copoun = 0;
                    dynamic shipping = 0;
                    dynamic shipping_discount = 0;
                    dynamic zid_cod = 0;
                    dynamic sub_totals_after_vat = 0;
                    dynamic vat = 0;
                    dynamic products_discount = 0;
                    dynamic voucherID = obj1.id;
                    dynamic createdAT = objOrdersID.order.created_at;
                    {
                        if (i.code == "coupon")
                        { copoun = i.value; }

                        if (i.code == "shipping")
                        { shipping = i.value; }

                        if (i.code == "shipping_discount")
                        { shipping_discount = i.value; }

                        if (i.code == "zid_cod")
                        { zid_cod = i.value; }

                        if (i.code == "sub_totals_after_vat")
                        { sub_totals_after_vat = i.value; }

                        if (i.code == "vat")
                        { vat = i.value; }
                        if (i.code == "products_discount")
                        { products_discount = i.value; }
                    }

                //purchasedaa
                 if (objOrdersID.order.shipping.method.code == "zid_aramex")

                {
                    cmd = new SqlCommand("zid_aramex", con);
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@products_discount", products_discount);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@shipping", shipping);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@voucherID", voucherID);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@createdAT", createdAT);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sub_totals_after_vat", sub_totals_after_vat);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@zid_cod", zid_cod);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@vat", vat);

                    try
                    {
                        con.Open();
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        WriteLogFile(e.ToString());
                    }

                    con.Close();

                }
```

Comment: Which line in the code throws exception?what does this code do? Why there are so many dynamic?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); is the code that throws the error, this is an api, that insert values into sql server database here I'm trying to get an order values to insert it into database by calling stored procedure and the dynamic variables are coming from API as Json format.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["System.ArgumentException: 'No mapping exists from object type Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue to a known managed provider native type.'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57176239/system-argumentexception-no-mapping-exists-from-object-type-newtonsoft-json-l)

Comment: This wouldn't be a problem if you used SqlParameter with SqlDbTypes instead of using `AddWithValue` with its often-wrong type guessing. Obligatory references to [AddWithValue is Evil](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/) and [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)